# Google cloud vpn : i install on Openvpn on google cloud when connect only reach ip not domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openvpn

I install OpenVPN from its original source on google cloud instance and installed correctly. it is working and connect from OpenVPN client and also change IP of PC but when I type example google.com no open
but when I type any IP address of any working server it shows and opens websites from IP but not domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are able to browse with IP but not with DNS name it seems like a DNS resolver issue. For this reason,I would start troubleshooting by checking the internal name resolver

cat /etc/resolv.conf

What we are looking in here is the information about the name server your are using.

At this point you might want to check "~/client-configs/base.conf" file as per the [OpneVPN configuration documention](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-8-adjust-the-server-networking-configuration):

> Finally, add a few commented out lines. We want to include these with
>   every config, but should only enable them for Linux clients that ship
>   with a /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf file. This script uses the
>   resolvconf utility to update DNS information for Linux clients.

"~/client-configs/base.conf

"# script-security 2"

"# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf"

"# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf"

> If your client is running Linux and has an
>   /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf file, you should uncomment these lines
>   from the generated OpenVPN client configuration file.

I would also check the OpenVPN "/etc/openvpn/server.conf" and make sure DNS configuration in plance. It would be also worthwhile to check network configuration specially IP forwading and make sure default route going out through intended interface

As per "[How To Set Up an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-7-configure-the-openvpn-service)" document the recommendation is:

> Your public interface should follow the word "dev". For example, this
>   result shows the interface named wlp11s0, which is highlighted below:
>
> default via x.x.x.x dev wlp11s0  proto static  metric 600

Comment: @HassanSardar  If my answer help to resolve this issue could you please accept it, thanks!